# OpenCV: src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size exception

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I have a code that calculate the rotation and translation matrix as following:

```
matrix Matrix<double> rt = new Matrix<double>(3, 4);  
if (positiveCount[0] > positiveCount[1])  
{  
    rt = R[0].ConcateHorizontal(T[0].GetCol(2));  
}  
else  
{  
    rt = R[1].ConcateVertical(T[1].GetCol(2));  
}
```

I get the error as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eals7.png), [image]

I checked all the matrices and elements, the size of all is match.

Has anybody experienced same error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem refers to the matter of adaptability of matrix dimensions.

In the else-part:

```
rt = R[1].ConcateVertical(T[1].GetCol(2));
```

is wrong, rt is a 3*4 matrix , R[1] is 3*3 and second column of T[1] is 3*1

so If we want to add T[1].GetCol(2) to R[1] horizontally we stick it to the matrix R to get a 3*4 matrix. There should be a size match when we are appending the rows/cols to another matrix.

so it should be replaced with :

```
 rt = R[1].ConcateHorizontal(T[1].GetCol(2));
```